# Scraping <span> tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page with BeautifulSoup and there are `<script>` tags inside `<span>` tag as shown below

```
<span data-link="{include tmpl='productCardOrderCount' ^~ordersCount=selectedNomenclature^ordersCount}"><script type="jsv#28_"></script>
<script type="jsv#27^"></script>
<script type="jsv#29_"></script>
<script type="jsv#26^"></script>
более 20 раз
<script type="jsv/26^"></script>
<script type="jsv/29_"></script>
<script type="jsv/27^"></script>
<script type="jsv/28_"></script>
</span>
```

But as `<script>` tags are not parsed as HTML in bs4, following code returns `<span>` tag without the text (`"более 20 раз"`)

```
rating = soup.find("p", {"class": "order-quantity"})
```

How can I get the text within the `<span>` tag?

Comment: Is the page loaded dynamically? does the text appear when using `print(soup.prettify())`?

Comment: BS4 will parse script tags, it just doesn't execute them. But if the text is in the HTML it should be returned.

Comment: @MendelG no it does not include any of <script> tags. This is what is prints:
<p class="order-quantity j-orders-count-wrapper hide" data-link="class{merge: selectedNomenclature^ordersCount &lt; 1 toggle='hide'}">
             Купили
             <span data-link="{include tmpl='productCardOrderCount' ^~ordersCount=selectedNomenclature^ordersCount}">
             </span>
            </p>

Comment: @SofiyaChobanyan The page is loaded dynamically. See [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Thank you, will check it out

Answer (score 0):

The text is under the tag `<script type="jsv#26^">`. You can search for it using `soup.find("script", type="jsv#26^")`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<span data-link="{include tmpl='productCardOrderCount' ^~ordersCount=selectedNomenclature^ordersCount}"><script type="jsv#28_"></script>
<script type="jsv#27^"></script>
<script type="jsv#29_"></script>
<script type="jsv#26^"></script>
более 20 раз
<script type="jsv/26^"></script>
<script type="jsv/29_"></script>
<script type="jsv/27^"></script>
<script type="jsv/28_"></script>
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("script", type="jsv#26^").find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
более 20 раз
```

Comment: The code throws the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'